# Using log-log graph to find equation of power law relationship?

Tags: r, power-law

I have a set of data that I think forms a power law relationship, however I am struggling to work out the equation of the relationship.

Here is a subset of the data I am working with:

```
df <- data.frame('x' = c(0.25, 1, 2, 2.75, 4.25, 6.5, 8, 13.25, 16.25, 19.25, 19.75, 26.5, 31, 37.75),
                 'y' = c(4.485605e-08, 1.430240e-08, 7.638950e-09, 6.776308e-09, 3.269885e-09, 
                     2.609455e-09, 4.378785e-09, 2.260540e-09, 2.039074e-09, 7.119317e-10,
                     2.252598e-09, 1.617082e-09, 7.511261e-09, 1.519275e-09))
```

Ploting this, I thought that the graph resembles that of y = 1/x:

[image]

I then plotted the log-log of the graph to see if it produced a straight line (indicating a power relationship) and attempted to fit a linear model to it to find the slope and the intercept.

[image]

The slope of the line was found to be -0.6099 and the intercept -18.178. However, when I put this back into the equation to work out the value of y for a given value of x it is way off.

For example if x=0.25 then y = (10^-18.178)*(0.25^-0.601).

This calculates y to be 1.527x10^-18 when the value of y for that data point was actually 4.486x10^-8.

I thought that perhaps is it simply that the heteroscedacity of the varience violates an assumption of the linear regression such that I can't use it for anything more than calculating the slope.

Am I correct, or is there something I've missed? Why is this value so far off?

Comment: Look at this near-duplicates:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331178/extracting-power-of-a-power-law-from-data,   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118334/power-law-fitting-and-testing,    https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199126/how-to-show-a-random-variable-is-power-law-distributed-and-estimate-its-paramete

Comment: Thank you, I have seen that one links a paper explaining better ways to calculate the coefficients for power law relationships which I will check out.

Comment: You're fitting using natural logarithms but using a power of 10 in the intercept calculations.

Comment: @NickCox I have literally just realised this after working through yoav_aaa's answer below and now feel rather foolish.

Comment: Happens to us all. Ideally you'd now just delete the thread. But there is an upvoted accepted answer (which doesn't really explain the issue!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following calculation and got a different y value for x=0.25.
Intercept and slope are similar to OP's question.

```
x = (0.25, 1, 2, 2.75, 4.25, 6.5, 8, 13.25, 16.25, 19.25, 19.75, 26.5, 31, 37.75)
y = (4.485605e-08, 1.430240e-08, 7.638950e-09, 6.776308e-09, 3.269885e-09, 
                 2.609455e-09, 4.378785e-09, 2.260540e-09, 2.039074e-09, 7.119317e-10,
                 2.252598e-09, 1.617082e-09, 7.511261e-09, 1.519275e-09)
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x , 'y': y})
my_df.loc[:, 'log_x'] = map(lambda x: math.log(x), my_df['x'])
my_df.loc[:, 'log_y'] = map(lambda x: math.log(x), my_df['y'])
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(my_df['log_x'].values.reshape(-1, 1), my_df['log_y'].values)
model.coef_
[-0.60989947]
model.intercept_
[-18.17749636096132]
X = 0.25
log_y = model.intercept_ + model.coef_ * math.log(X)
y = math.exp(log_y)
print(y)
2.970364e-08
```

Comment: Interesting, could you post the values of model.coef_ and model.intercept_ please? I want to see how they vary from those calculate in the model I produced in r

Comment: I have just realised the cause of the issue was me using a power of 10 after using natural logs. D'OH!